# Array não está sendo criado corretamente

Tags: javascript, angularjs, array

Tenho uma variável do `AngularJS` que guarda todo um jSON que carrego, os dados do jSON é parecido com esse:

```
{
    "Products": "Pimenta Vermelha muito boa",
    "Product_Code": "XXXXX",
    "RTV": "Alisson Acioli",
    "Regional": "Sudeste",
    "Cliente": "AGRO",
    "Estado": "MG",
    "Pricing_Zone": "XXX",
    "Quinzena": "Q2",
    "New_Product_Description": "Old Product",
    "Active_Ingredient": "Pimenta Vermelha",
    "Familia": "Pimenta",
    "Group": "Grupo do IA",
    "Linha": "Albaugh",
    "Devolução_Faturamento": "Faturamento",
    "Dia": 10,
    "mes": 1,
    "ano": 2015,
    "Concatenar": "",
    "Crop": "22 - CROP",
    "Version": "OPQ",
    "Tipo_Nota": "",
    "Data_Lancamento": "",
    "Data_Vencimento": "",
    "Prazo": "",
    "Condicao_Pagamento": "",
    "IGM": 1.0,
    "COGS": 2.0,
    "Net_Sales_VP": 1.000,
    "Net_Sales": 500,
    "Volume": 2,
    "ICMS_Tax": 100,
    "Freight": 100,
    "Interest": "-",
    "Receita_Invoice": 3.000,
    "Preco_Lista_Invoice_a_vista": "3,9",
    "Preco_a_prazo": "3,9",
    "Faturamento_Lista_Invoice": 10,
    "Net_Sales_Lista": 10,
    "Discount": "-2%",
    "Range_Capaing": "#N/D",
    "Range_Capaing_2": "#N/D",
    "Preco_Net_Lista_usd": "3,6",
    "IGM_Lista": 2.957,
    "Cambio_Dia": "2,571",
    "Faturamento_rs": "R$ 1.500",
    "Cambio_mes": "",
    "Faturamento_usd_Financeiro": ""
  }
```

Eu faço o filtro desses dados e insiro em uma variável que é um array. Até ai tudo bem, tudo funcionando.

O que eu tenho que fazer é criar um array com alguns dados desse jSON, assim:

```
/* Variáveis para gerenciar o filtro */
        var GraphOne = [];
        var GraphTwo = [];

        /* Variáveis para inserir no Highcharts */
        var HighchartsOne = [];
        var HighchartsTwo = [];

        $scope.filteredDados.forEach(function(arrayItem){

            if(arrayItem.Condicao_Pagamento != ''){
                GraphOne[arrayItem.Condicao_Pagamento] = GraphOne[arrayItem.Condicao_Pagamento] || [];
                GraphOne[arrayItem.Condicao_Pagamento].push(arrayItem.Net_Sales);
            }

            if(arrayItem.RTV != ''){
                GraphTwo[arrayItem.RTV] = GraphTwo[arrayItem.RTV] || [];
                GraphTwo[arrayItem.RTV].push({netsales:arrayItem.Net_Sales, igm: arrayItem.IGM, familia: arrayItem.Familia});
            }
        });
```

No primeiro bloco que ele cria um array e insere as condições de pagamento:

```
if(arrayItem.Condicao_Pagamento != ''){
                    GraphOne[arrayItem.Condicao_Pagamento] = GraphOne[arrayItem.Condicao_Pagamento] || [];
                    GraphOne[arrayItem.Condicao_Pagamento].push(arrayItem.Net_Sales);
                }
```

Ele insere certinho. Eu faço um **console.log(GraphOne);** e ele me retorna o array certo. Mas no segundo bloco que é o problema. Eu coloco o `console.log(GraphTwo);` e ele aparentemente no console me da o resultado:

> Array[ ]

E depois de alguns segundos que clico nesse `Array[ ]` ele me informa os dados que tem nele, que no caso é o que eu preciso. O estranho é que quando aparece esse `Array[ ]` e eu clico nele imediatamente não acontece nada, mas depois de alguns segundos, se eu clicar novamente, ele me exibe. O ruim é que preciso ler esse `Array` mais pra frente no código, mas acho que o código pensa que é um array vazio e não lê. Já o do primeiro bloco lê normalmente.

Não sei se é porque o indice dele (GraphTwo[arrayItem.RTV]) é um nome que contém espaços tipo **Alisson Acioli**, mas realmente não sei o que pode ser.

Comment: Você está usando a estrutura de dados errada, não? Você não quer um array, você quer um objeto

Comment: Mostre qual seria o objetivo do objeto que vc está gerando e também a parte que ele faz o `GraphTwo`

Comment: Existem muitos pontos que precisam de atenção aqui @Alisson Acioli. O Exemplo que você postou nunca vai entrar na condição porquê a Condicao_Pagamento está vazia. Segundo que acho que aqui `GraphTwo[arrayItem.RTV] = GraphTwo[arrayItem.RTV] || [];` está errado. Na linha de baixo ele tenta acessar `GraphTwo[arrayItem.RTV].push` mas arrayItem.RTV pode não existir. Terceiro, se você clica mais uma vez para exibir o array, ou é problema de sincronia ou bug. Quarto, ficarei feliz em ajudar com um exemplo verificavel, talvez no JSFiddle.